# bash calling a function via $(functionname) does not work

Tags: bash, function

I found on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters/index.html in listing #7 the following call to a function:

```
iNewValue=$(testthis)
```

which seems to me more elegant than calling the function and getting the return value like this:

```
testthis 4
echo "Now we have a result: $?"
```

When testing this it doesn't work - try this code

```
#!/bin/bash
#==============================================================
function testthis(){
   echo "In testthis with Param: $1"
   iResult=42
   return $iResult
}
#==============================================================
echo "Starting first run"
iNewValue=$(testthis 1 )
echo "First run ended with: $iNewValue"
echo "Starting second run"
testthis 2
echo "Second run ended with: $?"
```

I am getting:

```
Starting first run
First run ended with: In testthis with Param: 1
Starting second run
In testthis with Param: 2
Second run ended with: 42
```

I would expect:

```
Starting first run
In testthis with Param: 1
First run ended with: 42
Starting second run
In testthis with Param: 2
Second run ended with: 42
```

Please note that the actual output prints first the line after the call to the function and then the output from the function. What's going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An assignment like that captures stdout from the function not the return.Instead of using return you can just echo whatever you want to return. Obviously if you want to also print to the screen that becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$()` captures output from a function not the return code. To capture the return code you need to check `$?`.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the example. Thanks for clarifying.